# python elementtree xpath - insert variable in findall @name=VARIABLEHERE

Tags: python, xpath, xml-parsing, elementtree, findall

Is it possible to pipe in a variable to the `@name` attribute?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('C:/test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

somelist = [x.text for x in root.findall(".//actionList[@name='VARIABLEHEREinsteadoftext']//value")]
```

I need to get all the values only from a specific actionlist filtered by its name and ignore all the other actionlists. It works fine with

```
[@name="ACTIONLISTNAME"]
```

but I´d like something like this:

```
X = ACTIONLISTNAME
[@name=X]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use *string formatting*:

```
value = "ACTIONLISTNAME"
root.findall(".//actionList[@name='%s']//value" % value)
```

Answer (score 0):

the string formatting answer from @alecxe works fine, but if you want to use the [F-strings formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498), you can do this instead:

note the double curly brackets escaping in the schema part

```
xml_element.findall(f"{{x-schema:schema.xml}}row[@{attribute_name}='{attribute_value}']")
```